# Accessing another processor's local APIC

Tags: x86, operating-system, x86-64, osdev, apic

The documentation for the Intel 64 and IA-32 says that the local APIC's register space can be remapped to other physical address.

My question is, is it possible to access other processor's local APIC register space when they are mapped to different physical addresses?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, each CPU can only access its own APIC.